# Buffered Output from httpResponse.end()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In .NET, the description of `httpResponse.end()` states "Sends all currently buffered output to the client". Can anyone explain to me what that means? Specifically what is 'buffered output'? I am asking because I was asked to replace `httpResponse.end` with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`. This is causing issues when there are files involved, so I'm guessing that phrase has something to do with it.

Comment: What is causing issues and what type of issues?

Comment: Art do a MSDN Google search you would probably get a faster response because you would be able to read what and which each one means

Comment: When you write to a stream, the data you write to it usually doesn't get transported immediately.  It goes to a buffer which holds the data which is to be sent.  When a stream is flushed, the data that is in the buffer gets sent and the buffer is cleared.  What it's effectively saying there is that it is flushing the response.

Comment: @zespri I am not 100%, pretty much some data in a chart is being converted to an Excel. The entire process is quite complicated and I am still trying to debug it. But, as soon as I remove `httpResponse.end` the Excel file is generated with errors.

Comment: So, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @JeffMercado Ok, so I think I was on the right track, I tried flushing the buffer (`httpResponse.Flush`) before doing the `CompleteRequest` but this caused a different hard error stating that "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent".

Comment: @zespri httpResponse.End is automatically causing an exception, while it is handled, it worsens performance, some of my managers want to see if changing this will improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffered output is the output that your program has already produced, but has not forwarded to its intended destination yet.

Buffering is used a lot with I/O operations to avoid the cost of sending/writing the data in small increments: rather than passing the output to its destination as you write, the system collects larger chunks of it in a memory area called "the buffer", and sends/writes the data only when a certain size is reached.

There are two ways a buffered data makes it to its destination:

1. The amount of output reaches a certain threshold, or
2. You invoke some method to "flush" the buffer explicitly.

`httpResponse.end` is one such method: it empties the buffer by sending everything that you have written so far to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sending every single bit of information as soon as you write it to the output stream, it stores what you've written in memory until it has "enough" data that it considers it worth taking the time to send it to the client.  The size of the buffer can vary widely depending on the context and reason for buffering data.  To "flush" a buffer is to process all pending data in the buffer (in this case, the processing means sending it over the network to the client).  That's what `end` is doing in your case.

Buffering can be done for many reasons, but usually it's a matter of performance.  It would be very wasteful and time consuming if you sent a network packet for every single character you wrote to your stream, or (in many cases) every string passed to `Write`.  The application will perform faster by sending fewer, larger, packets of information.

Answer (score 1):

Buffered output means any output that is ready to be sent to the client, but not sent to the client yet.